# does Kotlin now supports cross-platform mobile development?

Tags: android, kotlin-multiplatform

I want to know if i can use the Kotlin language to develop cross-platform mobile applications just like Flutter?

I actually developed a mobile application using Kotlin and i want to have the iOS version of the application.

Answer (score 0):

Except UI you can write most of your business logic in KMM

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to KMM: https://kotlinlang.org/lp/mobile/ - "Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile is an SDK for iOS and Android app development. It offers all the combined benefits of creating cross-platform and native apps."